# asp and ms-access db - how to import data from xls file

Tags: excel, ms-access, asp-classic

i want to allow the user to upload xls file with 9 columns and unlimited number of rows.
i will run over everyline and insert the data to the db

how do i read the xls file?

Comment: Do you have a reason to run over every line? If not, it is quite possible to write SQL that will insert Excel into Access in one statement. BTW ASP Classic or .Net?

Comment: CLASSIC ASP - can you give me explnation for what you said?

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the XLS by opening an ADO recordset which pulls in the spreadsheet's data.

This example reads data from a spreadsheet named Billing Summary which includes column names in the first row..

```
Public Sub ReadSpreadsheet() 
    Const cstrFolder As String = "C:\Access\webforums" 
    Const cstrFile As String = "ExampleFinance.xls" 
    Dim strConnect As String 
    Dim strSql As String 

    Dim cn As Object 
    Dim rs As Object 
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _ 
        cstrFolder & Chr(92) & cstrFile & _ 
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";" 
    cn.Open strConnect 
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM [Billing Summary$] WHERE SomeField Is Not Null;" 
    rs.Open strSql, cn 

    Do While Not rs.EOF 
        '* do something with each row of data *'
        'Debug.Print rs!SomeField '
        rs.MoveNext 
    Loop 

    rs.Close 
    Set rs = Nothing 
    cn.Close 
    Set cn = Nothing 
End Sub
```

If that particular connection string doesn't work for you, look at other examples of Excel connection strings at [Connection strings for Excel](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

**Edit**:  That example works in Access.  But you said ASP.  I think it will work there, too, if you drop the data types from the variable and constant declarations: `Dim strSql` instead of `Dim strSql As String`

Answer (score 1):

Example of using an SQL statement to update Access from Excel.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\docs\dbto.mdb"

cn.Open scn

sSQL = "SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM "
sSQL = sSQL & "[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Docs\From.xls].[Sheet1$]"

cn.Execute sSQL, recs

MsgBox recs
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I had to load an excel spreadsheet to a DataSet - this got me there...

[Code Project Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelToDataset.aspx)

I used Option 1 - the Preferred method!  Hope this helps...

Mike

Comment: but i'm using classic ASP not .NET