# Populate Access table from Excel worksheet

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I found some code online that exports my Excel data to an Access table. The problem is that it creates the headers correctly but does not populate the data at all. How do I tell Excel to go through the data and export those fields?

Here's the code:

```
Sub Z_CreateTable()

'If this subroutine throws errors, remember to go to:
'Tools > References and select 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects #.# Library'

Dim dbConnectStr As String
Dim Catalog As Object
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbPath As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rngDB As Range
Dim wbPath As String
Dim stSQL As String
Dim strTable As Object

'Set database name here
dbPath = "T:\Projects\testdata1.mdb"
dbConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"

'Create new database
Set Catalog = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Catalog.Create dbConnectStr

'Connect to database and insert a new table
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
cnt.CursorLocation = adUseServer
With cnt
   .Open dbConnectStr
   .Execute "CREATE TABLE tblSample ([FIELD1] text(50) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[NAME] text(150) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[BLANK] text(10) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[CLASSID] text(10) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[TYPE] text(5) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[FIELD2] text(5) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[FIELD3] text(5) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[FIELD4] text(15) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[START YEAR] text(15) WITH Compression, " & _
             "[END YEAR] text(10) WITH Compression)"

End With
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

See: [asp and ms-access db - how to import data from xls file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157575/asp-and-ms-access-db-how-to-import-data-from-xls-file/4159258#4159258)  You can update from Excel using fairly standard SQL without first creating a table and without iterating through rows, which is very slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data from our client is an Excel file. I just wanted to convert it to a database for ease of matching it up with data I had from another source. I know enough VBA to hammer things into place but I don't know SQL at all.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! A `Select Into` statement would be much faster and easier.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas, if you are shaky on VBA and do not know SQL, work from the Access end and use the straightforward import tools to import the Excel sheet, as @Beth says.

Comment: Note that the code in the cited URL uses `IMEX=2`, which can cause data type problems (e.g., postal code columns where you want everything treated as text so that leading zeroes are not lost). Using `IMEX=1` will cause all columns to be treated as text, and will solve a lot of import problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing from the Access database?  You can create your own table first and that gives you more control over the field data types and indexes.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with VBA, but isn't he setting the datatype in the `Execute` statement with `text(50)` etc?

Comment: This is the last part in a series of macros that I run in Excel. I was hoping to do all the automation in Excel because I'm more familiar with it than Access.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that this code will only create the table.  To insert the records, you'll need to follow this up with an Execute that uses "INSERT INTO tblSample" and then each Excel row.

I don't know how to do this in VBA, but I could do it in VB using a `For Each row In {table}.Rows...Next` statement, so maybe Googling `For Each` syntax in VBA would help you.  Or maybe someone here can actually give you a good example.

EDIT:
Something close to this might work

```
For i = startRow to endRow
     cnt.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSample VALUES (" & _
                  Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & Cells(i, 2).Value & _
         --And so on
         & ")"
Next i
```

You'd have to set the values for the start and end rows.  This loop would go through each row in your range and insert the value of the cell in that row into the field you specify. You'll need to make the order the same as the columns in your table, so you might have `Cells(i, 2).Value` first, for instance.

Try executing it immediately after your `With` block, before the `Set cnt = Nothing`.

EDIT: Using SELECT INTO

```
.Execute "SELECT * INTO tblSample FROM "[{Your version of Excel};
          DATABASE={Your Excel spreadsheet}].[{Your sheet name}]"
```

Replacing your existing .Execute block.

Comment: Yea, I don't know VBA either. You'll notice I got this code online somewhere. I know there's something missing but I don't know how to write it myself.

Comment: Just to clarify, `Cells(i, 1).Value` refers to Column A?

Comment: Yes, the notation (I believe) is Cells(row number, column number). If the columns in Excel are zero-indexed, Column A will be zero, but I think they are one-indexed, so Column A is 1.

Comment: It gave me an error message, saying: `syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'JOHNFRANK0204282'`. The name John Frank is the first row in the data. Those numbers after it do no appear anywhere in that row. I don't know what this means.

Comment: Are you using the `& "," &` to insert commas between the values?

Comment: See Remou's answer; much more straightforward than mine.

Comment: I copied your code straight into Excel. I tried to put the `","` before the next line of code but it gave me an error after the quote saying it should be the end of the line. I see that you have it embedded in the middle of the first line of CELLS code.

Comment: Argh, I'm sorry, I don't know what it could be then. Unless you forgot the & ")" at the end?

Comment: What's the format for `[My Version of Excel]` if I'm running Office 2010?

Comment: Whatever I put in that field, it says `can not find file U:\MR_Thomas\<whatever I enter>`. The U: drive is our individual user folder on the network. I'm not sure why it's pointing there.

Comment: I tried using Excel 8.0, Excel 14.0, xl14, xl8, excel14, excel8, Excel 14, Excel 8...

Comment: It is using `U:\MR_Thomas\...` because that is your working directory.  Try explicitly specifying your spreadsheet path (C:\MyFolder\MyWorksheet.xls) so `"SELECT * INTO tblSample FROM [Excel 8.0; C:\MyFolder\MyWorksheet.xls].[Sheet1$]"`

Comment: The worksheet location doesn't seem to be the issue. It's still having problems identifying the Excel 8.0 or Excel 14.0 location.

Comment: Maybe try Excel 12.0 or [Excel 12.0 xml](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-35680.html)?

Comment: I'm back to your originally suggested code and I'm getting the error `No value given for one or more required parameters`.

Comment: Ok, try adding `dbFailOnError` after your insert statement: `.Execute "Insert...", dbFailOnError`

Comment: Maybe you have to explicitly specify the column names in VBA, so alter your insert statement to `"INSERT INTO tblSample([Field1], [Name], ...) Values("` etc

Comment: This is really frustrating. I'm getting the same error message. I'm thinking maybe it has to do with something else...?

Comment: Ok, last try before I go home.  Maybe replace `Cells(i, 1)` etc with `Range("A" & i).Value`, `Range("B" & i).Value` but you might have to escape the quotes around the "A", which is something I also don't know how to do in VBA. If that doesn't work, maybe edit your question with your best new attempt. Sorry I couldn't get this one for you.